# How to use java.util.Scanner from scala

Tags: scala

I tried to use **java.util.Scanner** from scala:

```
val scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
val line = scanner.readLine()
println(line)
```

Either by pasting on scala REPL or by running `scala file.scala`, I get this:

```
:2: error: value readLine is not a member of java.util.Scanner
val line = scanner.readLine()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`java.util.Scanner` has no `readLine` try `nextLine`.

```
scala> val scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
scanner: java.util.Scanner = java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

scala> val line = scanner.nextLine()
line: String = foo
```

Comment: Duh scala, that is what I meant! hehe

Comment: tab-complete on scanner in the REPL is helpful. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way seems to be using `JavaConverters` to use the `Scanner` as an `Iterator`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
...
val input = new Scanner(System.in).asScala
input.head // first element
val asList = input.toList // scala list
```